# visual c++ 2010 can't create a new win32 console project

Tags: c++

when I try to create a new c++ console project as I always do
I was shocked , The image Explain
when I type my project name and choose win32 console application and click ok I don't know what the hell was that appeared on the screen !!
the image : https://i.imgsafe.org/e6d125d.png
any help appreciated , thank you

Comment: The C++ project wizard is implemented by an embedded WebBrowser and executes Javascript.  Something rather bad happened to your browser configuration and it isn't very likely to be anything benign.

Comment: Your computer might have picked up a virus?